# merging a list of dfs on index values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I merge a list of multiple dfs into a single df based on index values where some values are the same and others are unique?

I would like the output to be the combined df with the missing rows so that although I have multiple dfs which is dynamic in length

df1:

```
 x
0,2
1,3
2,4
```

df 2

```
  y
0,1
2,2
3,2,
4,3
```

combined:

```
x,y
0,2,1
1,3,nan
2,4,2
3,nan,2
4,nan,3
```

I tried using `df = pd.concat(list_of_dfs)` But it just gave a waterfall effect
as in

```
  x, y
0,2,nan
1,3,nan
2,4,nan
0,nan,1
2,nan,2
3,nan,2
4,nan,3
```

and when I tried to to use join etc it just broke and gave me the index and no values

Comment: Did you tried df1.join(df2, how="outer")?

Comment: yes it produced the same result as inner as in the waterfall effect

Answer (score 0):

This is my x df

```
    x
idx 
0   22
1   55
2   66
3   44
4   15
5   65
```

This is my y df

```
y
idx 
0   26
1   53
2   45
8   89
4   65
9   32
```

This is the output I got for `df_x.join(df_y, how = 'outer')`

```
x   y
idx     
0   22.0    26.0
1   55.0    53.0
2   66.0    45.0
3   44.0    NaN
4   15.0    65.0
5   65.0    NaN
8   NaN 89.0
9   NaN 32.0
```

Isn't this what you were looking for?